# MvcContrib.CommandProcessor.RulesEngine tutorial(s)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, rule-engine, command-pattern, codecampserver

I am studying the CodeCampServer.

I am confused about the ASP.NET MvcContrib.CommandProcessor.RulesEngine.

Are there any tutorials about the RulesEngine of the MvcContrib?

Or can anybody of you explain me how does this work and what benefits I gain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any tutorials about the RulesEngine of the MvcContrib?

No.

The only way you can learn about it, its to look in the source code: http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=8120&tab=artifacts&buildTypeId=bt100

The last commit to this project was in 16 Dec 09, and this project is **far** from being complete (and therefore success). I think it's nice project, but to implement any rule you need to create so much code in so many places, so I don't like it.

I'm currently looking for using something else, like [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/Wikipage) and [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Is the MvcContrib RulesEngine the Tarantino RulesEngine? As far as I know the guys of Headspring are involved in both frameworks. For met it seems that they have put there RulesEngine in the MvcContrib, doesn't they?

Comment: The whole MVCContrib project is dead? Or just the RulesEngine part?

Comment: As far as I know the guys of HeadSpring built the CodeCampServer with their Tarantino RulesEngine. "Now" they changed to MVCContrib.CommandProccesor.RulesEngine. I think that they have put their Tarantino RulesEngine in the MVCContrib project. But I am not sure.

Comment: I think that RulesEngine migrated to MvcContrib.

Answer (score 3):

The Tarantino Rules engine has been moved into MvcContrib..  A series of blog posts and presentations are in the works to help document how to use the engine.  Code Camp Server is the best example of how to use it.

Comment: These will  will be posted to the mvccontrib.org project website.

Comment: Did this ever happen? I'm having no luck finding any mention of the rules engine on the MVCContrib project site.